# Spring autowired Exception (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException)

Tags: spring, autowired

After a long research and lost a day I decided to write here to find an answer of the autowired error below.

I didn't find the problem. I got error below when I run the application

`ERROR: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.donguk.condo.service.MemberService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.donguk.condo">
            <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- iBatis -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

    <bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlMapClientTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.donguk.condo"  use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml" />
                <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**MemberController**

```
package com.donguk.condo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.donguk.condo.service.MemberService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/member")
public class MemberController {

    @Autowired
    MemberService memberService;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public void list(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("list", memberService.list());
    }
}
```

**MemberServiceImpl**

```
package com.donguk.condo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.donguk.condo.dao.MemberDao;
import com.donguk.condo.vo.Member;


@Service
public class MemberServiceImpl implements MemberService {

    @Autowired MemberDao dao;

    @Override
    public List<Member> list() {
        return dao.list();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have, by any chance, other `applicationContext*.xml` files in your project?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your configuration that I can see. Can you post the log you get at application startup?

Comment: `<param-value>classpath:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>` this doesn't match `applicationContext.xml`. Remove the `*`. Also is your `applicationContext.xml` on the class path or in `WEB-INF\spring` like the one from the servlet.

Comment: @M.Deinum are you sure * doesn't match? * refers to zero or more characters. Spring uses Ant-style pattern matching for that.

Answer (score -1):

You disabled the component scan default filter, so auto scanning will only search for Components, as you have configured. Add Service to that filter list for component scanning.

Comment: Can you please help me understand the -1?